# Select element by element's content

Tags: javascript, html, list, select

I have list:

```
<ul class='mates'>
   <li class='m' id='1'>Jakub</li>
   <li class='f' id='2'>Vinnie</li>
   <li class='m' id='3'>David</li>
</ul>
```

How can I select 'li' tags "ONE BY ONE" to be checked if their content (between 'li' tags) is equal to 'xyz'.

```
element = document.getElementsByClassName('.mates').firstChield.innerHTML;
do {
    if(){
        //do something
    }
}while (element = element.nextSibling);
```

but I'm not getting even far enough to select firstChild. This error is showing in console: "Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined". This needs to be done in plain JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery?

Comment: Assessment. It have to be plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<ul class='mates'>
   <li class='m' id='1'>Jakub</li>
   <li class='f' id='2'>Vinnie</li>
   <li class='m' id='3'>David</li>
</ul>
<script>
var mates = document.getElementsByClassName('mates')[0];
for (var i=0; i< mates.childNodes.length; i++){
    if(mates.children[i].innerHTML == 'Vinnie') alert("Got you! ID "+mates.children[i].id)
}
</script>
```

Comment: how would you remove this element from DOM?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
instead of `alert()` line make it `mates.children[i].parentNode.removeChild(mates.children[i]);`

Answer (score 2):

Drop the dot in the parameter. Like this:

```
element = document.getElementsByClassName('mates').firstChild.innerHTML;
```

The dot is not a part of the name of the class.

**EDIT** also notice that the question originally had a typo in `firstChild`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `element` variable is not an element (its value is probably `undefined`). It should work if you use it like this:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('mates')[0].firstChild;
do {
    if(element.innerHTML == 'foo'){
        //do something
    }
} while (element = element.nextSibling);
```

The code above fixes:

- The class name as pointed out by @Renan
- The typo in `.firstChild`

Also note that `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, so you have to grab the first one in the list (index `0`) to reach your `<ul>`.

Finally, keep in mind that you'll be looping over all children of the `<ul>`, including empty text nodes (see a demonstration at http://jsfiddle.net/58ZZF/). This can be avoided if you use `firstElementChild` and `nextElementSibling`, but I'm not sure if there are cross browsers issues with those properties (MDN only says it's Firefox 3.5+).

Comment: I like this answer better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Few mistakes

1. Class name to `getElementsByClassName` should not have `.`
2. Spelling mistake in `firstChild`
3. `getElementsByClassName` returns an array, not a dom reference
4. When using `nextSibling` it could return text nodes also, you need to check the [nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) to make sure the element is a element node(nodeTye = 1), also you can check the `tagName  == 'LI'`

Try

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('mates')[0].firstChild;
do {
    if(element.nodeType == 1){
        console.log(element.textContent)
    }
}while (element = element.nextSibling);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cZvc/)

Comment: 5-`'.mates'` should be `'mates'` like you did